# Deep Tree Structure as Menu/Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I have a deep tree structure which should be rendered at the front-end like a menu structure in the browser.

I had a look at [Bootstrap4 NavBar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) but I am unsure if this is the right tool.

Since the tree is deep it should get loaded lazy (via ajax). The tree has 5k entries and a maximum depth of 7 levels.

Which open source library could help here?

Answer (score 1):

I feel [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/menu/) have enough nav and menu components to get this job done!